# Excel - How do I determine how much of a period of time fits certain critera?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time

I work at a place where certain times of the day pay more than others, and I was trying to write a formula to parse out how much "premium" time is contained during a given shift. Basically, any time between the hours of 22:00 and 05:59 pays more. Given the following start/end times, how can I create a formula(s) to create a table similar to what's below? I don't have an issue with the total time formula, just the premium/regular times that are giving me fits.

| Start Time | End Time | Total Time | Premium Time | Reg. Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07:30 | 16:00 | 8:30 | 0:00 | 8:30 |
| 04:15 | 15:45 | 11:30 | 1:44 | 9:46 |
| 16:00 | 23:30 | 7:30 | 1:30 | 6:00 |
| 22:30 | 04:35 | 6:05 | 6:05 | 0:00 |
| 21:30 | 07:30 | 10:00 | 7:59 | 2:01 |

I really haven't had any luck figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _startTime,A2,
     _endTime,B2,
     _paymoreTimeS,TIME(22,,),
     _paymoreTimeE,TIME(5,59,),
     _totalTime,MOD(_endTime-_startTime,1),
     _regTime,IF(_startTime<_endTime,
       MAX(0,MIN(_endTime,_paymoreTimeS)-MAX(_startTime,_paymoreTimeE)),
       MAX(0,_paymoreTimeS-_startTime)+MAX(0,_endTime-_paymoreTimeE)),
     _premiumTime,_totalTime-_regTime,
     HSTACK(_totalTime,_premiumTime,_regTime))
```

---

You can also use a <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> to spill as an array.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _startTime,A2:A6,
     _endTime,B2:B6,
     _paymoreTimeS,TIME(22,,),
     _paymoreTimeE,TIME(5,59,),
     _totalTime,MOD(_endTime-_startTime,1),
     _regTime,MAP(_startTime,_endTime,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x<y,
      MAX(0,MIN(y,_paymoreTimeS)-MAX(x,_paymoreTimeE)),
      MAX(0,_paymoreTimeS-x)+MAX(0,y-_paymoreTimeE)))),
     _premiumTime,_totalTime-_regTime,
     HSTACK(_totalTime,_premiumTime,_regTime))
```

---